# Running computations on a remote server using 2 possible methods. Which is ideal?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, nfs

So, this is more of a general question than a specific problem. I'm using AWS and I have my main web server on an m1.medium instance but there are some computationally intensive tasks that I want to run so I created an high compute (multicore, high speed) c1.medium instance as well.

I was thinking of putting all the scripts I want to run in the compute server. These are obviously separate volumes but I wanted to know which would be a better approach.

1. SSH + call the script on the compute server or
2. NFS mount the compute server and call the script

I'm fairly sure I know the behavior of #1 but I'm not sure about #2. If I did that would it use the CPU on the compute instance? Because that's the whole point in splitting them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is... no. The script is called on the m1.medium instance, so the CPU there serves that script. The NFS server running on the high compute instance will consume some CPU, but minimal. What youve said is sound.

Comment: "The program runs on the CPU of the system it was started on" is the short version :-)